# Liferay YUI Treeview without icons

Tags: yui, liferay-aui

I'm using this code to create a YUI TreeView. Is it possible to have childs without expanding icon or the file-icon? I only want to have the check-icon for them.

```
<div id="treeView"></div>

YUI().use(
  'aui-tree-view',
  function(Y) {
    new Y.TreeViewDD(
      {
        boundingBox: '#treeView',
        children: [
          {
            children: [
              {label: 'Child 1', leaf: true, type: 'check'},
              {label: 'Child 2', leaf: true, type: 'check'},
              {label: 'Child 3', leaf: true, type: 'check'},
              {label: 'Child 4', leaf: true, type: 'check'},
              {label: 'Child 5', leaf: true, type: 'check'}
            ],
            expanded: true,
            label: 'Checkboxes'
          }
        ]
      }
    ).render();
  }
);
```

Comment: It seems like a good framework but the documentation is non existent. I have the same issue & its very frustrating

Answer (score 0):

`Y.TreeNode.ATTRS.cssClasses.value.file.iconLeaf = 'none';`

Paste this one before `new Y.TreeViewDD(` and you will get `<i class="none"></i>` wich results in no icon for icon leaf.

`Y.TreeNode.ATTRS` is a static for all tree nodes. There is a lot of intresting in it print it to console!